# Specifying Server-Side Encryption does not work using JAVA SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

In my case, I want to encrypt each file which is uploaded to S3 bucket. I have followed AWS documentation on this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SSEUsingJavaSDK.html . 
[image]

the encryption already set using AES256 as following evaluation
[image]

The document have been uploaded successfully. But unfortunately, the server side encryption is not set.
[image]

Could anyone help me on this ? 
Thank you,

Cheers,
Putra

Comment: Your screenshot shows a last modified date from September. Are you sure that you are getting the properties for the correct file?

Comment: Sorry for wrong screenshot, I am already update it.